# Adding template specialization for all types given in variadic template

Tags: c++, templates

I have a big homework assignment on templates, and part of it is creating a structure `template <typename... Types> struct Foo`, which contains a public structure `template<typename Type> struct Bar` which shares (in public `type` definition) a structure in which we must include a public method `template<typename Type> static constexpr size_t count();` which outputs `1` if a type was given in arguments to `Foo` and `Bar` or `0` otherwise. Example (the following code should compile):

```
using FooBar = Foo<foo1,foo2,foo3>;

using Foo1Type = FooBar::Bar<foo1>::type;
// foo1 was given as argument to Foo and Bar
static_assert(Foo1Type::count<foo1>() == 1);
// foo2 was given as argument to Foo, but not Bar
static_assert(Foo1Type::count<foo2>() == 0);

using Foo4Type = FooBar::Bar<foo4>::type;
// foo4 was not given as argument to Foo
static_assert(Foo4Type::count<foo4>() == 0); 
static_assert(Foo4Type::count<foo1>() == 0);
```

It looks pretty hardcore to me (I'm new to templates, just started reading abount them), it seems like we must iterate through variadic template arguments to `Foo`, and during iteration somehow create new specializations for inside structure `Bar`... I have never seen anything like this, so I can only guess how it can be done.

So, am I thinking in a good way about this problem, or should I approach it somehow different? I would be grateful for any help (not just the full solution) - any useful links are welcome.

Comment: Which C++ standard version are you allowed to use? `constexpr` means C++11 or later.

Comment: @melak47 The C++ tag refers to the latest C++ standard.

Comment: I can even use C++17 is I want to

Comment: @melak47: as OP uses `static_assert` without message, it seems to be c++1z.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, your inner function is simply something like:

```
return contain<Type, TBar>{} && contain<Type, TFoos...>{};
```

And that struct contain may be written like:

```
template <typename T, typename ... Ts> struct contain;

// Partial specializations
// Empty case
template <typename T> struct contain<T> : std::false_type {};

// Found
template <typename T, typename ... Tail>
struct contain<T, T, Tail...> : std::true_type {};

// Not found, iterate the list
template <typename T, typename Head, typename ... Tail>
struct contain<T, Head, Tail...> : contain<T, Tail...> {};
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/vEYz2t)